# HTML5 MP3 Audio Player for FireFox, Invisible SWF Fallback?

Tags: html, firefox, mp3

Is there a way to create a SWF fallback for an HTML5 Audio Player that is simply an invisible SWF that can report back and forth to JavaScript/JQuery?

This way, I can have an HTML5 Player, keep the controls, but when it needs to use Flash as a fallback, it simply calls the swf file as an engine for playing the MP3 in Firefox and all the html controls remain.

What Im trying to avoid is creating a duplicate interface completely in flash just for firefox users.  Im also trying to avoid making copies of my library of 150mb mp3 audio files to OGG format simply to make the app work for FireFox users.  It just doesnt seem logical.

How is BandCamp doing it?  Or Audio JS?

http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) it provides an HTML5 player with SWF fallback.